# Convert multiple arrays to arrays inside one array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I need to collect multiple arrays that come from a ajax request they are collected like this using js:

```
var date=[];
$("#avc [name='date']").each(function(i){
date.push($(this).val());
});

var pi=[];
$("#avc [name='pi']").each(function(i){
pi.push($(this).val());
});

var name=[];
$("#avc [name='name']").each(function(i){
name.push($(this).val());
});
```

So here i have collected array date, pi and name on client side when these arrays are passed to server side i get this:

```
   $date=array("27/01/2014", "12/01/2015", "12/04/2018");
   $pi=array(22, 55, 03);
   $name=array("lambda", "alpha", "beta");
```

I need to transform it to:

```
$x= array
  (
  array("27/01/2014", 22, "lambda"),
  array("12/01/2015", 55, "alpha")
  array("12/04/2018", 03, "beta")
  );
```

Comment: Why not make that in JS in the first place?

Comment: yes might be better but i have no clue how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the node lists are equal in length you can simply do this in JavaScript

```
var data=[];
$("#avc [name='date']").each(function(i){
    data.push([$(this).val(), $("#avc [name='pi']")[i].value, $("#avc [name='name']")[i].value]);
});
```

When converted from JSON to PHP array the array above will create the array below.

```
$x= array
 (
    array("27/01/2014", 22, "lambda"),
    array("12/01/2015", 55, "alpha")
    array("12/04/2018", 03, "beta")
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't elegant, but you could do something like:

```
$x=array();
foreach($date as $k => $v){
  $x[$k]=array($v,$pi[$k],$name[$k])
}
```